# Place images in page center in epresent-mode

Tags: org-mode, images

I am using the display inline images code from this [org-display-inline-images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621495/emacs-org-display-inline-images) link.`

But when i run `epresent-run` to present it, the images are placed in top left corner. How can i place them in the page's center (i mean, centering image both horizontally & vertically)

Css code might be like this,

```
.centered {
 position: absolute
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `#+ATTR_HTML: :stye your-css`?

Comment: hi wvxvwx, i inserted image using C-u, C-c, C-l, interactive prompt. and i am not able to edit this link like in a normal text file....

Comment: This isn't exactly what I meant. You can put `#+ATTR_HTML` in the Org file on the line preceding the image (I believe that images aren't embedded in text, otherwise you'd not want to center them on the screen, would you?). See here: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/images-and-xhtml-export.html#sec-3

Comment: `* Picture\n
#+ATTR_HTML: style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;"\n
[[file:Pictures/image1.jpg]photo]]
`  it didn't help though

Comment: That doesn't seem like a correct syntax to me. Did you look into generated HTML to make sure the style attribute was indeed added? I think it has to be `#+ATTR_HTML: :style "position ..."`. Note the colon before the "style".

Comment: properties name needn't be prefixed with `:` courtesy, the same link that you provided. and again, prefixing `:` didn't help also. `epresent-run` may not be understanding the `ATTR_HTML` directive.

Comment: Hm... I'd then look into a possibility to add CSS file to the entire presentation. From looking at the sources of epresent it doesn't seem like they have a special export backend. Though I couldn't really find how they do the exporting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Above feature is not supported by epresent.

`epresent-mode` 
(derived from `org-mode`) doesn't export org files to html (or) any other format. It just changes how your org document is displayed. Some parts of the document such as TODO tags and property drawers are hidden, bigger fonts are used, and only one slide at a time is displayed.`

Courtesy: @tmalsburg -[git-talk](https://github.com/eschulte/epresent/issues/6#issuecomment-77003286)

Comment: Please mark your own answer as accepted if you believe it solves your question.